# Summing two rows without specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have such case, I want to sum two diffrent rows but I dont want to sum values in some colums.
For example I want to sum row 6 and 7 but without datas in columns with name "Charge", do you have any clue?

```
   Range("e5").Select
Do

If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(1#).Value Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(1#).Value Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select

Else

Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
End If
End If

Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
```

Comment: I don't think that the code you posted fits to your question. Please show us what you have tried to sum the rows - otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: well yeah this is the code that im using right now, but I need to change it because it sum everything in rows with the same specification in two cells. But I need to exclude from this rows the columns which names are "Charge" and "Number", and I dont know how to do this. I edit my question with this picture

Comment: You can sum everything and then substract the charge column from your Grand total

Comment: You can use `SUMIFS`

Comment: I dont know if I write it right, I need to sum two rows into one if they have the same ID, and after that delete one of them and go on with other rows, there can be 100 rows and only 35 with the same ID to sum. But i dont want to sum rows in red, because this are data that should be not sum

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question - at least add your last comment because it contains necessary information. Maybe you should read [ask] first.